# Including an iOS app within an app. Is this possible?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, api

I am a beginner in coding for iOS and swift, and learning to create my own app.

I have a basic idea in mind that'll help engineering students in their student life and professional career. In one section of the App I have an idea for it to include a very extensive calculator like WolframAlpha.

Can I, with permission from its owners, include WolframAlpha in a little section of my app without linking out of my app?

If so, is there a guide?

And is that what API is for?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can certainly call functionality from anywhere you like subject to legal constraints.  WolphramAlpha allows this through their API:

http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/

And the documentation is here: http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/documentation.html

It's standard REST so you should be good to go